# Is it me or is there a typo in this courseware entry?

Tags: java, return

I took this from an online [MIT courseware discussion](http://ocw.mit.edu/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-092January--IAP--2006/71545E62-D58B-4E36-BED3-0C87BFF90D9A/0/thissuper.pdf) (pdf warning):

```
public class Human { 
 private String name; 
 ... 
 public Human(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public String getName() { 
  return String; 
 }
}

public class Student extends Human { 
 private String username;
 public Student(String name, String username) {
  super(name);
  this.username = username;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return username;
 }
 public String getRealName() { 
  return super.getName();
 }
}
...
public class World {
 ... 
  void someMethod() { 
   Student alice = new Student("Alice", "abc"); 
   System.out.println(alice.getRealName()); // what gets printed?
```

Why does getRealName return anything.  I know it returns Alice because the constructor is called by super(name) but my question is about:

```
return String;
```

Why doesn't getName in the Human class have to be

```
return name;
```

Comment: why did I get a close?  just curious.

Comment: I hate closes without comments--but I'd guess that it's because it's a pretty straight-forward error that wouldn't have even compiled--it's more of a proofreading question than a programming question.

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be. It's a typo. This code as you have pasted it would not compile.

Comment: I guess I got bamboozled by it coming from MIT so I figured it must be me that's wrong and not them.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  It's a typo and should be `return name`.

Please notify the instructor, or the contact person for the class, so they can update the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

unless the three-dot-area contains something like

```
private String String = "Alice";
```

but, nay, I guess it's a typo ;-)

Comment: Surprisingly this would compile. :)